# When QuerySet is evaluated when get_queryset is overridden

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Have not understand very well how QS is evaluated when overriden. Based on [leedjango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62976955/how-to-override-get-queryset-in-django) question, we are able to override get_queryset in a view class. In this same example, I have not been able to understand when the get_queryset method is returning the QS evaluated. We know how QS are evaluated in general, as it is explained in [eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254516/when-does-djangos-values-values-list-get-evaluated) question.

For instance, I have the following components:
Front End sending GET request to the appropriate URL:

```
//Dashboard.js:
export default function Dashboard() {
    const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
    const getUserSchools = () => {
        getUser({ email: keycloak.email }).then((response) => {
          const { data: users } = response;
          if (users.length) {
            const appUser = users[0];
            axios
              .get(`/api/school/list/?user_id=${appUser.id}`)
              .then((data) => {
                setTableData(data.data.results);
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                /* eslint-disable-next-line */
                console.error(err);
                setTableData([]);
              });
          }
        });
      };
```

Then, it hits the school-urls.py looking for which view is related to that URL:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^list/$", SchoolsList.as_view()),
]
```

SchoolsList is the appropriate View which is overriding get_queryset and returns the queryset:

```
#list.py
class LargeResultsSetPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 100
    
class SchoolsList(generics.ListAPIView):
    pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination
    serializer_class = SchoolGetSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = School.objects.all()
        
        user_id = self.request.query_params.get('user_id', None)
        if (user_id is not None):
            queryset = queryset.filter(user_id=user_id)
        
        return queryset.order_by('id')
```

Using the following serializer:

```
#get.py
class SchoolGetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    nearest_community = SchoolCommunitySerializer(required=False)
    nearest_post_secondary = SchoolPostSecondarySerializer(required=False)
    regional_district = SchoolRegionalDistrictSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = School
        fields = (
            "id",
            "address",
            "nearest_post_secondary",
            "nearest_community",
            "regional_district",
        )
```

In the above snippets, when the queryset is evaluated?

When sending the GET request from the Front End or Postman, I can see queryset is returned twice, the first time the queryset is returned almost immediately. However, GET request is not finished until after 50 seconds again the queryset is evaluated and returned (in here I do not know how is evaluated). The query executed by hand delays 750ms. is not a heavy query, it is just selecting a record by id.

Would you have any idea why get_queryset is hit and immediately return without executing the queryset and then after 50 secs is querying the database? How could I enforce querying the database right away?

**Edit:**
QuerySet is evaluated until Serializer is executed. If nearest_community and nearest_post_secondary fields have heavy queries. Then, the execution of queryset would delay. If you simply the serializer, then you would get the response immediately.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the query, the problem is that the serializer needs to make additional queries to fetch the related objects. You should load these elements in the same query, with **``**:

```
class SchoolsList(generics.ListAPIView):
    pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination
    serializer_class = SchoolGetSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = School.objects.all()

        user_id = self.request.query_params.get('user_id')
        if user_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(user_id=user_id)

        return queryset.select_related(
            'nearest_community', 'nearest_post_secundary', 'regional_district'
        ).order_by('id')
```

Since these serializer might query additional items, it is even possible that you should select additional fields, but these are not mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Querysets are lazy. They are evaluated when you use them, not when you filter, order_by... so on. `YourModel.objects` is a Manager (see [ModelManagers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/managers/)), with it you can do mass management easily (your queries). You need to check the number of connection to database, specially in loops. It's very important (don't make assumptions). `Model.object.get_values()` for get dictionaries can cause extra costs, for example, and you can fix it writing an specific Manager. If you need individual things, use model methods.

Did I answer your question?

---

This is wrong:

```
 return queryset.order_by('id')
```

You can't do it. The query isn't done yet.
At least, do it:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
# code, code, code...

def any_view(request):
    # code, code, code...
    response = {'data': queryset.order_by('id').values()}
    return JsonResponse(response)
```